# How to use Row filter on DataView

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have datatable and that table have one column named as `joiningDate` which is in `mm-dd-yyyy` format. I want to filter that table on the basis of current month so I am using `DataView` for such operation my code is:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DataView dvUpcomingLeave = new DataView(dtLeaves);
dvUpcomingLeave.RowFilter = "DATEPART(Month, joiningDate) = " + now.Month;
```

But it showing me error that:

> The expression contains undefined function call DATEPART().

I think because `DATEPART()` is not function of ADO.NET, so any one can help me how can I solve this problem using `DataView` `RowFilter` only.

Comment: Exactly. `DATEPART` belongs on SQL Server. `RowFilter` filter your values based on your column values. Maybe you need to create one more column and keep month part of `joiningDate` and filter your values based on _that_ column.

Comment: could you use this example to get it: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/499468-how-filter-month-using-dataview-rowfilter

Comment: ya that's fine but i am trying to do it without any extra column.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with the abilities provided by the `RowFilter` expression (the same used for the [Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) property of a DataColumn)

However you could reach your goal with something like this

```
DataView v = dtLeaves.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("joiningDate")
                  .Month == DateTime.Today.Month)
            .CopyToDataTable().DefaultView;
```

A warning, this [CopyToDataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx) will fail if the input IEnumerable returned by the `Where` is empty, so it is better to split this in more than one line and test the results before proceding to the next step

```
var temp = dtLeaves.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("joiningDate")
            .Month == DateTime.Today.Month);
if(temp.Any())
    DataView dvUpcomingLeave = temp.CopyToDataTable().DefaultView;
```

Comment: ya but if data not found in result then also temp is not null so its always true.

Comment: Sure, changed to _if(temp.Any())_

Answer (score 0):

You have to put Date-Values in either quotation marks or hashtags ([Source: csharp-examples.net](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/))

So, in your case:

```
dvUpcomingLeave.RowFilter = String.Format("DATEPART(Month, joiningDate) = '{0}'",now.Month);
```

or

```
dvUpcomingLeave.RowFilter = String.Format("DATEPART(Month, joiningDate) = #{0}#",now.Month);
```

Comment: Sorry friend but it is not working showing me the same error.